# How to make users create their own attributes in core data xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I want to create an app that let's users create different set of lists. Is there a way to let users create an attribute for a certain entity in core data? For example, If I have an entity called "Lists" I want my users to be able to make an attribute called "Numbers". Is this possible?

Comment: Core Data does not support to change the data model at runtime.

Comment: @vadian oh is that so.... thanks I'll look for a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your users cannot create their own attributes in Core Data, you as developer create the Core Data data model and only you can change it.

If you need users to create their own attributes just make a data model yourself where you can store users attributes in a Dictionary or something similar...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I opted to use firebase instead.

Comment: Thats a great option as well...maybe you can accept the answer since as per your question it is not possible to use Core Data for this..

Comment: I will thanks for saving me a lot of time by the way.